# How set TOS field for Soap traffic of Apache

Tags: php, linux, apache, networking, soap

Recently I am doing QOS for our software system which consists of apache+php server app and a C++ server app. We want to use the TOS field in IP header to differentiate different services.

I know we can set the TOS field for c++ application traffic by calling setsockopt(fd, IPPROTO_IP, &TosVal, ...). However,I don't know how to set the TOS field for packets of soap traffic of apache using PHP.  I have below questions:

```
   1) Is it possible to set the TOS field when we are using php+apache to
      send a soap response.
   2) If the answer to question 1) is yes, then how?
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15300843/creating-a-soap-call-using-php-with-an-xml-body Does this helps.

Thanks & Regards,  
Alok Thaker

Comment: Thansk Alok, but this doesn't solve my problem. I want to set the ToS (type of service) field of IP header of a Soap response when using apache + php, other than set the contents of soap header.